# What means the error : ..."bytes to alignment boundary" in Xcode/Clang?

Tags: c++, xcode, warnings

`TransformNode with 4 bytes to alignment boundary`

And here is the code that cause this warning :

```
class TransformNode : public Node {
public:
    int number;

public:

    void test() { number = 12; }
};

//Node.h
class Node {
public:
    typedef std::set<Node *> ChildSet;

protected:
    ChildSet mChildren;
    Node * mParent;

public:
    Node(Node * parent=0) : mParent(parent) {}
    ~Node() {}

    Node * addChild(Node * node);
    inline Node * getParent() { return mParent; }

    const ChildSet &getChildren() const { return mChildren; }
};


inline void node_test() {
    TransformNode * node = new TransformNode;
    node->test();
    std::cout << node->number << "\n";
}

int main() {

    node_test();
    return 0;
}
```

The error happens when I derive **Node** class from the class TransformNode. I am using xcode 5.0 with all the warnings turned on and treating warnings as errors. I really want to understand what is going on with this code, so just turning off warnings or stop treating them as errors is not the way I want to handle this.

*EDIT: Added more code. Clarification on some details (in bold)*

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: should I add more code than that?

Comment: *should I add more code than that?* **Yes**. You still aren't showing where you are transforming a Node to a TransformNode. How can we tell where you went wrong without that critical piece of code?

Comment: this it the entire code I posted. Where it calls it and what the structures are. I have never seen this warning. I am still trying to get grasp of what it is...

Comment: This is **not** the your entire code. You aren't showing `TransformNode::test()`, for example. It's a bit moot since you accepted an answer.

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that. The function actually does nothing special. I am adding it to the code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're seeing is actually an error.  Generally, "all warnings" includes all kinds of stuff that are barely considered warnings; heck, for the most part they aren't even super informative either.

Alignment is an issue you probably don't care about unless you're working with very specific hardware like in an embedded system.  Probably what is happening is that your compiler defaults to 8-byte alignment, and when you define the `TransformNode` class, you are allocating 4 bytes for the `int` and "wasting" 4 more bytes to align the entire class to an 8-byte boundary.  The compiler warning is telling you about the "wasted" 4 bytes.  As I said, you probably do not care about this.

I think in general you'll just drive yourself mad if you have maximal warnings and warnings-as-errors turned on.  Probably more useful to step back one level of warning and then treat as error if you really want to be super-clean.

Reedit:  Clarified answer in light of recent edits.

Another thought:  Try adding another `int` in your `TransformNode` class and see if the warning goes away (I'm assuming it will because `int` #2 will "use up" the "wasted" 4 bytes).

You can also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_padding to understand the issue better.

Comment: That's a lot for the information. I added another `int` as you suggested and it actually took away the warning. Now, I am trying to find out what really caused this warning in the first place :)

Comment: After I read the article, I realized that this can be due to the fact that I am using a 64 bit architecture int my architecture. I changed it to 32 bit for now and no more warning about it :)

Answer (score 0):

What warning option did you enable to get this particular warning? I see only two possibilities.

- -Weverything
  Do not specify this option. This option is intended for internal Clang use only. See the first answer to this question at the Programmers sister site, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development .
- -Wpadded
  If you specifically asked to be warned about padding, why are you asking this question?

Don't turn on every possible warning flag. You'll end up getting a lot of false positives, and all that noise will make you missing the real warnings. Turn on the warning options that have a high signal to noise ratio, and then pay attention to each and every warning that is issued.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: A rationale for the downvote would be nice. I, for one, like using `-Werror` to make warnings become a compilation errors. Using `-Weverything`, or even `-Wpadded`, in conjunction with `-Werror` is a bad idea. It is a particularly bad idea if you are using some other code base over which you have no control.